# CSS file not found when pushing a Jekyll project to gh-pages remote branch and using jekyll-compass

Tags: compass-sass, jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-extensions

I was building my site with css and everything was working fine, both locally and remotely. Then I wanted to switch to sass. I installed jekyll-compass and now my sass files are being output as css files in my _site/css folder. Everything works well locally, but when I push them to Github, my styles are not being applied and I get a 404 on that css file. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of setting the output of your rendered SASS files to `/_site/css`, set the output to just `/css` *(the site root level)*.

What is happening is that locally SASS is running just fine and outputting into your `/_site/` directory as you'd expect. But in production on GitHub pages *(where the jekyll-compass gem isn't supported)* your CSS isn't being output into `/_site` at all because the plugin isn't being executed there.

It doesn't matter that it works locally from there because GitHub Pages runs the `jekyll build` command again once you push and generates `/_site/` afresh. So anything it doesn't support (i.e. jekyll-compass) doesn't make it into the production version of your `/_site` folder.

The workaround I've suggested works because instead of outputting the final CSS into a directory that gets overwritten when you push to GitHub pages, it will instead write it to a directory that is preserved even with a fresh build of the `/_site/` directory.

*Also of note, Jekyll 2.0 will support SASS, and you can even use the [2.0 alpha gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/jekyll/versions/2.0.0.alpha.1) locally if you want (although GH Pages won't be updated to 2.0 until it's officially released).*

Comment: Thanks for explaining. How do you change the SASS output destination within Jekyll?

Comment: Note that GitHub Pages has been upgraded to Jekyll 2.0 and will work as expected with Sass now.

Answer (score 1):

Very few plugins are supported by GitHub pages, it used to be none but now there are three. See [this page](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-plugins-with-github-pages) for more information.

You will need to compile the SASS and commit the generated CSS files.